# PSQL average with IF/ELSE

Tags: if-statement, average, psql

I have a psql table with columns including:   year, value, ... and so on.

I want to do something like this:

```
select 
CASE WHEN avg(value) >=0 then avg(value) 
     ELSE -999 
END
from my_table
where year >= 2000 and year < 2005 and value >= 0
```

So I want my average to ignore any years that have negative value, but for cases where all years have negative value, I want to return -999.

This query runs but doesn't return -999 in the case where all values are negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you're looking for something like:

```
select 
   coalesce(avg(value) filter (when value >= 0), -999)
from my_table
where year >= 2000 and year < 2005;
```

which returns `-999` if all values are negative *or* there are zero rows that match the `WHERE` clause. `avg` returns null if it doesn't get any input rows.

The `filter` syntax works only on newer PostgreSQL versions. For older ones you must use `avg(case when value >= 0 then value end)`.

Answer (score 0):

you have given in the where clause value>=0 This will only compute the average of non negative values, hence you will never get the average of negative values

```
where year >= 2000 and year < 2005 and value >= 0
```

Guess what you are trying to do is this

```
    select 
    CASE WHEN value >=0 then 
    (select avg(value) from t_table where value>=0)
         ELSE -999 
    END
    from table
    where year >= 2000 and year < 2005;
```

Comment: right, I don't want the average of negative values, I just want the place-holder value of -999 in that case. That's why I tried the 'CASE WHEN .... ELSE ...." approach above, but it has a flaw somehow.

Comment: remove the value>=0  clause, if your average will be negative you will get -999 in that case

Comment: right, sorry my question wasn't so clear. I want to ignore the negative values in the average. So the average will only include the years with value >=0.

Comment: see in that case the average will be done of all  the positive values which will  always be greater than zero, the else part will never be executed..